# Jhipster Entity and User data gone after MySQL runs out of memory

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, jhipster

I have an issue with Jhipster crashing and losing all entity entries. I'm using a Jhipster in production with a mysql database server on Docker. Every day or so the mysql database crashes and I have to restart the Jhispter application. When it restarts all of the mysql data is gone and doesn't come back on the reload. This includes both entities and user login information. I think I need to load in the entity data again somehow, but I'm not sure how.

How would I go about reloading the Jhipster user and entity data once the server crashes?
I have both MySQL and JHispter running with docker-compose.

Comment: Running docker-compose in production is not very common, the configuration that JHipster provided you is just a starting point, you must tune it for performance, security and take care of your data backups. So, what did you change to make it production ready?

Comment: I mainly added the old jhipster console, docker volumes, and changed passwords. I thought that Jhipster would automatically load the data from mysql when running it in production if the mysql data persited, but it doesn't seem to be loading in at all. I really just want one entry to be loaded in automatically when the jhipster application restarts since that's the only thing that doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: This sounds like you may be missing all forms of COMMIT to get your data recorded.

Comment: What do you mean by COMMIT? Also, I realized that the data is being saved, but it gets deleted when MySQL gets SHUTDOWN. I'm still not sure why it's getting that command, but the fact that the data is deleted is the biggest issue for me.